# Error:Unable to connect to database. Driver class not found: com.ibm.db2.jcc.D B2Driver

Tags: jdbc, db2, database-connection, driver

I am trying to connect to a DB2 database that I just created. I have CLASSPATH pointing to the two necessary jar files: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar

My connection configuration file looks like

```
database.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
database.url=jdbc:db2:test

database.userName=test
database.schemaNames=test
database.password=test

database.driverLocation='C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar'
```

When I try to connect I get the error:

```
Creating data source. Driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver, url: jdbc:db2:test, us
er: test, password: test

# Error:Unable to connect to database. Driver class not found: com.ibm.db2.jcc.D
B2Driver
# Cause:com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

I am fairly new to this so I would appreciate any help on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: The class path must contain fully qualified JAR file names, not the directory where they reside.

Comment: I've added the two necessary jar files to the CLASSPATH and continue to get the same error. I've updated the description to show this.